# SQL запрос на выборку с сортировкой

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Имеются две таблицы: `NEWS` и `COMMENTS`. Таблица `COMMENTS` содержит уникальный `comment_id` и связующий `news_id`.
Как составить запрос, чтобы получить список новостей, сортированный по количеству комментариев?

Comment: уточните такие детали как: надо ли отображать новости без коментариев, порядок сортировки.

Comment: @Bald56rus Нужен список всех новостей, включая и непрокомментированные.

Comment: @Pavel Если какой-то ответ Вам помог - выберите его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант со вложенным запросом:

```
   SELECT n.*, 
          IF(c.cntr, c.cntr, 0) cntr
     FROM NEWS n
LEFT JOIN (SELECT news_id, count(*) cntr
             FROM COMMENTS
         GROUP BY news_id) c ON n.id = c.news_id
 ORDER BY c.cntr DESC
```

Звёздочка здесь чтобы выбрать все поля из таблицы новостей - лучше, конечно, явно задать поля. Из-за LEFT JOIN в результатах могут быть NULL (там, где нет комментариев) - мы заменили их на 0. Результаты отсортированы по убыванию.

Можно просто получить идентификаторы новостей, у которых есть хотя бы один комментарий (упрощенный вариант ответа @Bald56rus).

```
  SELECT news_id
    FROM COMMENTS
GROUP BY news_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Здесь мы обошлись вообще без объединения таблиц. Минус этого подхода - нет информации о статьях (данных из таблицы NEWS) и в результатах нет идентификаторов новостей без комментариев.

Поэтому мы все-таки джойним таблицы (см. первый пример выше), однако используем LEFT JOIN, чтобы получить данные о числе комментариев для всех новостей.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Версия до вставленного IF работала, а теперь рузается на него: ORA-00904: "IF": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 11

Comment: @Pavel а у вас действительно MySQL? Не Oracle, случаем?

Comment: @Regent , виноват, у меня Oracle. Уже исправил в тегах

Comment: @Pavel поменяйте IF(c.cntr, c.cntr, 0) на nvl(c.cntr, 0)

Comment: @ApInvent Вот это работает, но выводит так, что запись с 3 комментариями выше записи с 5, а те у которых нет комментаривев, внизу: _SELECT n.*, 
          nvl(c.cntr, 0) cntr
     FROM NEWS n
LEFT JOIN (SELECT news_id, count(*) cntr
             FROM COMMENTS
         GROUP BY news_id) c ON n.news_id = c.news_id
 ORDER BY c.cntr;_

Comment: @Pavel Ну так у Вас так и написан order by. Если Вы хотите, чтобы было от большего к меньшему - надо добавить `desc`, как сделано в ответе и поменять `order by c.cntr` на `order by nvl(c.cntr, 0)`. В итоге будет `order by nvl(c.cntr, 0) desc`

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант предложенного ранее решения, лишь в другой нотации:

```
select n.*, nvl(cnt,0) comments_count
  from news n,
       (select news_id, count(*) cnt
          from comments
         group by news_id) c
 where n.id=c.news_id(+)
 order by cnt desc nulls last;
```